# Не выводит элемент ImageView на устройство

Tags: android, android-studio

Элемент ImageView не выводит на устройство, но при этом эта картинка есть на экране предпросмотра.

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="178dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/lock" />
```

так выглядит код вывода картинки. На устройстве вместо картинки просто пустота, пробовал другие картинки и просто цвет все-равно не выводится почему-то.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `android:src="@drawable/lock"` вместо `app:srcCompat="@drawable/lock"`